# Asynchronous : Why is form post redirecting?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Objectives :

- Post a form
- Upload a file to AWS S3
- Show a valid message on HTML page.

Using Node JS, HTML.

The page keeps on waiting from server.
From the server, it seems like all functions have finished running.

Would you share any experience of this problem / any way of debbuging it?

HTML :

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit_form/">
    <input type="hidden" id="avatar_url" name="avatar_url" value="/public/default.png" />
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="Full name" /><br /><br />
    <input id="form_input" type="submit" value="Update profile" />
</form>
```

My Form functions :

```
(function(){
    document.getElementById("form_input").onclick = init_upload;
})();

function init_upload(){
   var file = dataURItoBlob(document.getElementById('preview').src);
   if(file == null){
      alert("No file selected.");
      return;
  }
   get_signed_request(file);
}

function get_signed_request(file){
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var file_name = "an-image-name";
 xhr.open("GET", "/sign_s3?file_name="+file_name+"&file_type="+file.type);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState === 4){
    if(xhr.status === 200){
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        upload_file(file, response.signed_request, response.url);
        console.log("xhr status 200 : file : ", file);
        console.log("xhr status 200 : response.signed_request : ", response.signed_request);
        console.log("xhr status 200 : response.url : ", response.url);
    }
    else{
        alert("Could not get signed URL.");
    }
}
};
  xhr.send();
}
```

And the posts managing codes :

```
app.post('/submit_form', function(req, res){
  //something to be done
  console.log("submit form .....")
});

 app.get('/sign_s3', function(req, res){
 aws.config.update({accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY});
var s3 = new aws.S3();
var s3_params = {
  Bucket: S3_BUCKET_CREATION,
  Key: req.query.file_name,
  Expires: 60,
  ContentType: req.query.file_type,
  ACL: 'public-read'
};
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3_params, function(err, data){
if(err){
    console.log("/sign S3 : error");
    console.log(err);
}
else{
    var return_data = {
        signed_request: data,
        url: 'https://'+S3_BUCKET_CREATION+'.s3.amazonaws.com/'+req.query.file_name
    };
    res.write(JSON.stringify(return_data));
    console.log("/sign S3 : end");
    res.end("200");
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you share your code? This seems a bit vague

Comment: Would _you_ share your code?

Comment: It is probably doing what a form normally does, that is POSTing and redirecting / refreshing the page. You need to prevent the default behaviour.

Comment: Do you know how to do this?

Comment: take out `action="/submit_form/"` and just handle the form submission on the submit event in js, and return false:

Comment: You are calling the route `/submit_form`, which doesn't send a response (`res.send('foo bar')`), which means that request will stay open. Express ***needs*** for you to send a response

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a response using `res.status(200).end();` Otherwise, your client keeps waiting for a response from the server that will never arrive.